# preventing htmlentities from destroying utf8 characters ಠ_ಠ

Tags: php, security

I want to filter my output to make it safer from Cross site scripting (XSS) attacks so I am filtering output with htmlentities. The problem is, I am trying to make my application utf8 compatible so when I enter something like ಠ_ಠ I would like it to be maintained when retrieved from the database. Is there a simple solution to achieve this? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things

1. HTML sanitization is an *output escaping* task, not *input filtering*.  You should **not** do this task prior to storage, you should only do it prior to display.
2. If you are trying to prevent XSS, you don't need to use `htmlentities()` - `htmlspecialchars()` is sufficient. `htmlentities()` is used only when trying to render a content from a character-encoding that is disparate from native encoding.
3. [Both](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) [functions](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) accept a character encoding as the third argument.

So, finally:

```
echo htmlspecialchars( $content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

Where if you used ENT_NOQUOTES you could be vulnerable to some types of XSS.

Comment: As @The Rook said, you may want to escape quotes in some circumstances (e.g. html attributes, javascript function arguments).

Comment: @Artefacto html ignores backslashes,  its not like mysql.  You have to encode them and your encode function is flawed.  My -1 stands as long as your code is vulnerable.

Comment: @The Rook hum? htmlspecialchars encodes them in html entitities, doesn't escape them with backslashes.

Comment: @The Rook - quote marks are only dangerous if you're writing user-into into the attribute of another HTML element.  So using `ENT_NOQUOTES` vs `ENT_COMPAT` vs `ENT_QUOTES` is really more of a context-relevant *choice* than a "this one is always right" type of option.  I just happened to pick `ENT_NOQUOTES` for this example (completely arbitrarily) and I find it disappointing that out of all the information in my answer, that is what you focused on, and voted with.  Also, this is *my* answer, not Artefacto's.

Comment: I don't care if your vote stays. It's not my position, place, or right to talk you out of it.  I'm just saying it's not *always* vulnerable.  If you really feel *that* strongly about it - edit it.  This is a wiki-like site after all.

Comment: Actually the comment "you should not do that before storage" could be viewed as a problem. You want to escape strings when using SQL statements (i.e. pg_escape_string() and alike), but that has nothing to do with outputting HTML. (i.e. HTML output can generate XSS attacks, missing the pg_escape_string() can generate SQL Injections.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke What? *Could* be viewed as a problem?  If we were talking about SQL Injection here, then yes.  But we're not.  This is entirely about output escaping and preventing things like XSS and CSRF.

Answer (score 2):

`$var=htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");`

Comment: and that will still filter output the same wait entities would?

Comment: Look at the PHP documentation for how htmlspecialchars and htmlentities differ.

Comment: @Scarface  No,  its a lot better at stopping XSS than htmlentties().  There are cases where you don't need `<>`,  for instance if you are in a body tag and you inject an `onload=`,  and this will prevent that.